# IE Compatibility, margin issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, margin

I started at this company about a month ago and I've been trying to clean up their website. It's a real mess. My boss uses IE but I was using Chrome, just kind of running and gunning. The headline underneath the jQuery slider that reads: "World-Class Mechanical Engineers & Contractors - in Central PA" goes to the far left hand side of the `<td>`, but the other h1 doesn't. I want the site to render the same in Chrome as it does in IE, but the way that it looks in Chrome is what I want. In Chrome, the h1 pulls in 40px to the right, to indent it out. What am I missing, here?

http://www.enginuity-llc.com/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invalid markup. Notice how on the second line of the snippet below has a table element with the h1 as a child.

```
<tr>
    <td height="50" colspan="2" valign="bottom"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <h1 style="margin-left:40px">World-Class Mechanical Engineers & Contractors - in Central PA</h1>
        <p style="margin-left:50px; margin-right:75px">Enginuity, LLC is a local firm with decades of global experience in the HVAC and Plumbing sectors. Whether you're looking for a custom process design/build, a retrofit to existing HVAC equipment, service                  and maintenance, or sustainable energy solutions, Enginuity-LLC is your ultimate one-stop partner. What began in 2002 with four mechanical contracting veterans, has grown into an 85-strong firm that still delivers the best design, service, and                         support in the business.</p>
        <p style="margin-left:50px; margin-right:75px">Enginuity-LLC is more than just your local Energy Star Partner & MSCA Green-Star Recipient; we're your solutions provider for the life of your building. We've worked with large enterprises and small businesses, but regardless of what you need, you'll find a level of professionalism and experience unmatched in the HVAC, Plumbing, and Mechanical Contractor market.</p>
        <h1 style="margin-left:40px">We Specialize in:</h1>
            <table style="margin-left:80px">
                <tr>
                    <td width="180px">
                        <ul>
                        <li>HVAC</li>
                        <li>Plumbing</li>
                        <li>Medical Gas Piping</li>
                        <li>Pneumatic</li>
                        <li>Hydraulics</li>
                        <li>Steam</li>
                        <li>Compressed Air</li>
                        <li>Process Piping</li>
                        <li>Refrigeration</li>
                        <li>Utility Piping</li>
                        <li>Ventilation</li>
                        </ul>               
                    </td>
                    <td width="220px">
                        <ul>
                        <li>Centrifugal Chillers</li>
                        <li>Special Environments</li>
                        <li>Specialty Fabrication</li>
                        <li>Backflow Preventers</li>
                        <li>Fire Damper Inspection</li>
                        <li>Sheet Metal / Ductwork</li>
                        <li>New Construction</li>
                        <li>Tenant Fitouts</li>
                        <li>Restoration</li>
                        <li>Turn-Key Design / Build</li>
                        <li>Preventative Maintenance</li>
                        </ul>               
                    </td>
                    <td width="220px">
                        <ul>
                        <li>Energy Retrofits</li>
                        <li>Energy Optimization</li>
                        <li>Computer Rooms</li>
                        <li>Climate Control</li>
                        <li>Radiant Floor Systems</li>
                        <li>Geothermal Systems</li>
                        <li>Energy Audits / Benchmarking</li>
                        <li>Fire Damper Inspection</li>
                        <li>Liebert Certified Data-Aire</li>
                        <li>Electrical Controls</li>
                        <li>DDC</li>
                        </ul>               
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>

<td align="left" width="800px">
```

Also if you open developer tools in IE (F12), you will notice that it freaks out in that area (for me it shows a <> child, which is impossible)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS reset, then style your own margins.

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in
>   things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings,
>   and so on.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/